# R - Quantstrat Issue with prefer and getPrice

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, quantstrat, blotter

Currently working on a strategy in quantstrat using Quandl futures data. However, when I try to applyStrategy() after adding indicators, signals and order rules, I receive the following error message, `Error in getPrice(mktdata, prefer = prefer) : object 'prefer' not found`. `applyIndicators()` and `applySignals()` works well when debugging so the error is most likely in the processing of the rules. Below is the tail end of the mktdata variable that results after applying the signals in addition to the end part of the code.

mktdata:

[image]

Code:

```
initPortf(portfolio.mom, symbols=allInstruments, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.mom, portfolios=portfolio.mom, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initOrders(portfolio.mom, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.mom, store=TRUE)

#Indicators
strategy.mom <- add.indicator(strategy=strategy.mom, name="tsMOM", arguments=list(futDataRet = quote(Cl(mktdata)), momLookback=momLookback, tradingDays=tradingDays), label="tsMOM")
strategy.mom <- add.indicator(strategy=strategy.mom, name="retVol", arguments=list(futDataRet = quote(Cl(mktdata)), volLookback=volLookback, tradingDays=tradingDays), label="retVol")

#Signals
strategy.mom <- add.signal(strategy.mom,name="sigThreshold",arguments=list(threshold=posTradeThresh, column="tsMOM", relationship="gt", cross=FALSE), label="LongCond")
strategy.mom <- add.signal(strategy.mom,name="sigThreshold",arguments=list(threshold=negTradeThresh, column="tsMOM", relationship="lt", cross=FALSE), label="ShortCond")

strategy.mom <- add.signal(strategy.mom, name="sigFormula",  arguments=list(columns=c("tsMOM","LongCond"), formula="((LongCond != 1) & (tsMOM >= 0))", cross=FALSE), label="NeutralPosCond")
strategy.mom <- add.signal(strategy.mom, name="sigFormula",  arguments=list(columns=c("tsMOM","ShortCond"), formula="((tsMOM < 0) & (ShortCond != 1))", cross=FALSE), label="NeutralNegCond")

# Entry Rule
strategy.mom <- add.rule(strategy.mom, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="LongCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1000, ordertype="market", orderside="long", prefer = "Close", TxnFees = -100), type="enter")
strategy.mom <- add.rule(strategy.mom, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="ShortCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1000, ordertype="market", orderside="short", prefer = "Close", TxnFees = -100), type="enter")
# Exit Rule
strategy.mom <- add.rule(strategy.mom, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="NeutralPosCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty="all", ordertype="market", orderside="short", prefer = "Close", TxnFees = -100), type="exit")
strategy.mom <- add.rule(strategy.mom, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="NeutralNegCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty="all", ordertype="market", orderside="long", prefer = "Close", TxnFees = -100), type="exit")

applyStrategy(strategy=strategy.mom, portfolios=portfolio.mom, prefer="Close")
updatePortf(portfolio.mom)
updateAcct(account.mom)
updateEndEq(account.mom)
```

Output of `sessionInfo()`:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the output of `sessionInfo` into your question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Added output of sessionInfo.

Comment: I think I fixed this in revision 1611. Please update and retry.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That error is gone now. Thank you. But when I run checkBlotterUpdate() from Guy Yollin's demos/presentations. I get that the account and portfolio P&Ls don't match

Comment: This problem had already been fixed, but the user had not installed the updated package.

Comment: I can look into the difference you're getting from `checkBlotterUpdate`, but I don't think it's an appropriate question for StackOverflow. Please email me a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) and reference the relevant demo/presentation.